# Ultegra 6870 Di2 Synchro Shift

Tags: shimano, shimano-di2

I have an Ultegra 6870 Di2 groupset and I would like to use synchro shift.

In e-tube project, I select Customize, then Shift Mode Setting.

And I have an error message telling:

`If SM-BRM1/SM-BRM2/SM-BTR2 is connected, shift mode will not function even if set.`

What does it mean ? I can see that SM-BTR2 is the built-in battery, that I have on my bike.

Is it possible to use this function with 6870 ? If yes, how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to upgrade your groupset to be Syncro-shift compatible. All you need is the new BT-DN110 battery. Once you have the new battery, you just need to update all the firmware, then set it to Syncro-shift with the e-tube software.

Comment: [This article](https://www.bikeexchange.com.au/blog/upgrade-shimano-dura-ace-9070-ultegra-6870-di2-to-synchro-shift-how-to) explains how to do the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! But it's annoying to have to buy a new battery for that..

Comment: It's unfortunate, but the chipset in the battery is what runs the Synchro Shift processes so I don't think it's avoidable.

Comment: The hardware for that function sits in the battery. It is clever marketing to make you buy new stuff.

Comment: Better have it done at a licensed shop. The firmware update disabled the left grip which is the first in line to update and the whole system went belly-up. There's no backtrack and any update failure ends in a locked system.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information