# Can I upgrade to Synchro shifting on a 10s Di2 bike? (Ultegra 6770)

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shimano-di2

I bought a second hand bike with an existing Ultegra DI2 6770 groupset, which is a 10-speed group.  I would like to upgrade the components required in order to have syncro shift on it.

As far as I know syncro shift is not available for 6770 (10-speed Shimano Ultegra Di2). For 6870 (the first 11-speed Ultegra Di2 version), Synchro shift is available if we [update the battery to the BT-DN110](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/ultegra-6870-di2-synchro-shift?newreg=63f720ef8bb6447cab11d8aeaac8242d). (Note: the battery houses the computer system that enables Synchro shift.)

Thus I am wondering what components I need to upgrade from a 6770 groupset?

Comment: 6770 is 10-speed, 6870 os 11-speed.  Offhand, you're going to **need** at least the rear derailleur, 11-speed cassette, and an 11-speed compatible rear wheel.  You'll probably need more, though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle are you sure? The latest Di2 compatibility chart explicitly says that the DN-110 battery is compatible with 6770 levers. That battery has the hardware that enables synchro shift on 11s groups. This **implies** that the OP could update to this battery, update his/her component firmware, and enable Synchro shift. However, I'm having trouble finding reports that people have actually done this and got Synchro shift to work on their 10s Di2 groups. https://e-tubeproject.shimano.com/pdf/en/HM-CC.3.4.3-00-EN.pdf

Comment: @WeiwenNg That compatibility chart doesn't say using an RD-6770 results in an 11-speed system.  I assumed that after the upgrade the OP wants an 11-speed system, and I'd be extremely surprised if Shimano (or any other manufacturer...) made a 10-speed high-end electronic rear derailleur that only needs a firmware update to be an 11-speed high-end electronic rear derailleur.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I see. My initial reading of the post was that the OP was just asking what they need to do to get synchro shifting on their 10s group. Going back to what they originally wrote, I still think this is the more likely interpretation. Also, if the shifting parameters are given by the battery computer and none of the important derailleur dimensions changed, then the 6770 RD **should** have been convertible to 11s through a firmware update. That means it could have been technically possible. I agree that most manufacturers probably wouldn't go and actually do it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for your contribution, yes I wd like to keep the 10s if possible otherwise it will be too expensive. Would changing the battery and the junctionbox suffice ?

Comment: ddb306: that's what I'm trying to figure out. The compatibility chart clearly states that the DN-110 battery is compatible with your shifters. So, it seems **possible** that changing the battery and junction box would make your bike Synchro-capable. However, I am not able to **confirm** this.

Comment: Ok, so that's how far I went too

Comment: http://carltonbale.com/shimano-di2-everything-you-need-to-know/

Comment: "Unfortunately, 6770 only supports multi-shift of the rear derailleur. It cannot be upgraded to syncro-shift between front and rear derailleurs."

Comment: So I think I need to change the front and rear derrailleurs junction box and battery

Comment: Bah ... I read through the link you provided. That's too bad. In that case, you're correct that you basically need all the shifting components, the junction box, and the new battery. You don't need to change the crankset if you don't want to. You know, on Stackexchange, you're allowed to answer your own question. Since you found the critical bit of information, you should do so.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed a Di2 6770 10spd front and rear derailleur with a BT-DN110 internal battery.

I can confirm that once I update firmware on all the components, eTube does ***NOT*** allow me to set up synchro shifting.

Very disappointed considering the battery has all the hardware necessary to support it.